# xargs won't take carriage return literal in command argument

Tags: bash, xargs

Consider the following grep command that is intended to match crlf line endings in the file listed in the variable `source_files`.

```
# In reality the variable "source_files" is constructed dynamically
source_files="/foo/bar.txt"
files_with_lf=$(echo "$source_files" | xargs -t -0 grep -Ua '\([^'$'\r'']\|^\)$')
```

This will print:

```
grep -Ua \([^]\|^\)$ /foo/bar

grep: Unmatched [, [^, [:, [., or [=
```

It seems the `\r` literal isn't correctly passed. How can I make sure that it does?

For the record, I'm using

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(5)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: `echo "$source_files"` -- What do you think this does? Don't think it does what you intended it to do!

Comment: I expect it to put the content of `source_files` on the stdout.

Comment: You are grepping the literal string `/foo/bar.txt`, not the contents of that file. Perhaps you want `cat` instead of `echo`.

Comment: how so? there is an `xargs` call in between...

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke: It does not.. unfortunately. State your intentions clearly for us to help you out.

Comment: @Inian care to elaborate?

Comment: @Inian from the bash man page: "writes each given STRING to standard output"

Comment: `echo` just prints the value of a variable to `stdout`, does not expand the contents of the file, `cat` is meant for that. But you don't need `cat` either for your case. You can `grep` on the file directly

Comment: The call to `xargs` is exactly supposed to do that...

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke: Yes, just the literal string in this case `/foo/bar.txt` and not its actual contents.

Comment: Which is exactly what grep needs! grep [OPTION]... PATTERN **[FILE]...**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133549/discussion-between-inian-and-chiel-ten-brinke).